# Unable to create maven project in eclipse(oxygen)

Tags: maven

GETTING THIS ERROR:

```
Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed
```

Comment: Someone pls help me

Comment: Running Java7 ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve].  Good question get more answers, more quickly.